# What issue in the shot in unity 3D?

Tags: unity, c#, 3d, multiplayer, character-development

when the start game in the client [localserver], the bullet can't forward in the space just fixed in the Gun, here image about what I say:https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjMPG.jpg "image"

network manager
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksHBg.jpg "image"

player
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kdr2.jpg "image"

bullet
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9Nz5.jpg "image"

and this my script

```
    void Update()
   {
      if(!isLocalPlayer){
          return;
      }
      if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0))
      {
         CmdBulletFire();
      }
   }
  [Command]
  void CmdBulletFire()
  {
    // create the bullet prefab
    GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, bulletSpawn.position, bulletSpawn.rotation);

    //add velocity to bullet
    bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward * 50000f));
    //Spawn the bullet
    NetworkServer.Spawn(bullet);
    //Destroy the bullet
    Destroy(bullet, 5f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am sharing my code which works fine use this on hope so it will work

```
 public   void OnButtonDown()
{

    GameObject bullet = Instantiate(Resources.Load("bullet", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
    Rigidbody rb = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    FireClick.Play ();
    bullet.transform.rotation = Camera.main.transform.rotation;
    bullet.transform.position = Camera.main.transform.position;
    rb.AddForce(Camera.main.transform.forward * 500f);
    Destroy(bullet, 3);




}
```

use this

```
 rb.AddForce(Camera.main.transform.forward * 500f);
```

Comment: thank u , but no problem with non network, the problem in the networking the bullet can't move

Answer (score 1):

'Vector3.forward' is shorthand for writing Vector3(0, 0, 1).

What you're looking for is 'transform.forward'. This is the direction your transform is facing.

```
 bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.forward * 50000f, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

Comment: no problem with non network , the problem in the networking the bullet can't move

Comment: Did you try setting 'TransformSyncMode' = SyncRigidbody on the NetworkTransform component of the bullet prefab?

Comment: yes but still the issue, but when removing the Network Manager and set try again the code is run without issue! did you know what's happened about that ?